# Angularjs slider to choose date instead of number

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I would like to use Angular Materials slider to choose date.

I have created this codepen to demonstrate a simple slider that chooses a number.
https://codepen.io/helpme/pen/meLWBL?#

```
.sliderdemoBasicUsage input[type="number"] {
  text-align: center; }
```

However, I would like to modify this code such that the slider choose a date  instead of a number. The date is actually a month date and as the slider slides, the date changes by the month. The date is of the format `2004-06-01`, `2004-07-01`, `2004-08-01`.

Can the Angular Materials slider be modified to support date that follows my format? How can the codepen be modified to support it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have my solution to what you are looking for: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/avGJGp?editors=101

`HTML` important part is here:

```
  <md-slider flex="" min="1" max="12" ng-model="month" aria-label="red" id="red-slider" class="">
  </md-slider>
  <div flex="20" layout="" layout-align="center center">
    <input type="text" aria-label="red" aria-controls="red-slider" value="2008-{{month}}-1" disabled="true">
  </div>
```

I set `min="1"` and `max="12"` as the possible month range numbers that can be chosen, and the slider value is bound to `$scope.month` through `ng-model="month"`.

Changed the input type to `type="text"` and I set it's value to the string `"2008-{{month}}-1"`, where the year and day number always stay the same, but the month changes when you use the slider as it was bound to `$scope.month`.

The `Angular` controller would just stay this way:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.month = 4;
});
```

Comment: @user768421 cheers! I've edited the post with some more detailed information about the implementation.